# c thread concurrency and memory mix up

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a multithread program in C. there is only 1 thread function (thread_read_file), that will read a file content into a variable from a struct.
this function has an automatic variable thiscontent, in which the content of the file should be stored using fread.

the main program is executing 4 threads to read 4 different files at regular interval to update the content into memory.

no matter what I tried, I get the result followed by some garbage after some time.
I tried forcing adding a '\0' after my reading, but no, it would display the garbage anyhow.

here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WAIT_TIME 2

/* change_it:
 * 8: picture for texture 0 finished to load into ram, needs to be set to 2 afterwards
 * 7: picture for texture 0 loading
 * 6: picture for texture 1 finished to load into ram, needs to be set to 2 afterwards
 * 5: picture for texture 1 loading
 * 4: pre stage 1, initialize time variable for time constant blending
 * 3: initial -> allows initial loading of textures
 * 2: texture has finished changed, dont change it anymore
 * 1: initiate texture change
 * 0: don't change any texture */
int change_it = 0;
signed int offset = -1;
int check_id = WAIT_TIME*100+1;

typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t read_mutex; // synchronize access to reading flag
    int reading;                                // 0 = not reading , 1 = reading , 2 = finished reading
    char *content;                          // content of file
    char *file;                              // file to read
} struct_file_content;

struct_file_content struct_data_file[4];

char *file_content[4];

// temperature in abu dhabi
#define file1 "/home/tias/repository/data/temp_ad.txt"

// temperature in irsch
#define file2 "/home/tias/repository/data/temp_ir.txt"

// change EUR / AED
#define file3 "/home/tias/repository/data/change.txt"

// monitoring data used to color cubes
#define file4 "/home/tias/repository/data/summary.txt"

void change_or_not(signed int* offset, int* check_id, int* change_it) {

    if ( *offset == -1 ) {
        *offset = (signed int) ( time(NULL) ) % WAIT_TIME;
    }

    int delta       = (int) ( ( ( (long) time(NULL) ) - *offset ) % WAIT_TIME );
    int delta_id = (int) ( (long) time(NULL) % (WAIT_TIME * 100) );

    if ( *check_id > WAIT_TIME*100 ) *check_id  = delta_id;

    if ( delta == 0 && *check_id != delta_id && *change_it == 0 ) {
        //*change_it = 4;
        *change_it = 1;
        *check_id   = delta_id;
    }

    if ( delta == 0 && *check_id != delta_id && *change_it == 2 ) *change_it = 0;

}

void pretend_texture_blending ( int* change_it ) {
    static old_change_it = 0;
    static int ori = 0;
    if ( old_change_it == 0 && *change_it == 1 ) {
        ori = time(NULL);
    }
    if ( time(NULL) > ori && *change_it == 1 ) {
        ori = time(NULL);
        *change_it = 2;
    }
    old_change_it = *change_it;
}

void *thread_read_file(void *data) {

    struct_file_content *thisdata = data;
    int mutex_res;
    long length;
    char *thiscontent = NULL;

    // lock mutex
    mutex_res = pthread_mutex_lock(&thisdata->read_mutex);

    if (mutex_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "thread_read_file() failed to acquire mutex: %s\n", strerror(mutex_res));
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "thread_read_file: mutex locked for file: %s\n",thisdata->file);
    }
    // end locking procedure

    // let's open the file now
    FILE *f = fopen(thisdata->file, "r");

    // let's get the size of the file and bounce if it is too large
    // if size is acceptable, read the file into memory
    if (f) {
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell(f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);

        if (length > 39) {
            fprintf(stderr, "file %s is too big\n", thisdata->file);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        thiscontent = (char*)malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char));

        if (thiscontent) {
            fread(thiscontent, 1, length, f);
        } else {
            perror("malloc(3) error");
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        fclose(f);

        // puzzling result is here :
        // first run with the 4 threads always work fine
        // next runs will randomly display mixed values / other memory locations

        fprintf(stdout,"thiscontent: %s length was %d for file %s\n",thiscontent,length,thisdata->file);

    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file %s\n", thisdata->file);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    // file read and fd closed

    // free old allocation of this content
    free(thisdata->content);
    thisdata->reading = 2;
    // assign new result to newly freed char*
    thisdata->content = thiscontent;

    // unlock mutex as everything has been updated

    mutex_res = pthread_mutex_unlock(&thisdata->read_mutex);

    if (mutex_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "thread_read_file() failed to release mutex: %s\n", strerror(mutex_res));
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout,"thread_read_file: mutex unlocked for file: %s\n", thisdata->file);
    }
    // end unlock mutex procedure

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    static int init = 1;

    int p,q,r,curtime;
    float X,Y;
    static int data_update_done[4] = { 0,0,0,0 };

    static pthread_t thread_file[4];
    static int thread_res[4] = { 0,0,0,0 };

    static char *files[4];
    files[0] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(file1));
    files[1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(file2));
    files[2] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(file3));
    files[3] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(file4));

    int mutex_err[4];

    // init = 1
    // => launches the 4 threads for reading the 4 files
    // 
    if ( init == 1 ) {

        strcpy(files[0],file1);
        strcpy(files[1],file2);
        strcpy(files[2],file3);
        strcpy(files[3],file4);

        for ( p = 0 ; p < 4 ; p++ ) {

            mutex_err[p] = pthread_mutex_init(&struct_data_file[p].read_mutex, NULL);

            if (mutex_err[p] != 0 ) {
                fprintf(stderr, "pthread_mutex_init(3) error: %s\n", strerror(mutex_err[p]));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            struct_data_file[p].reading = 1;
            struct_data_file[p].content = NULL;
            struct_data_file[p].file = files[p];

            thread_res[p] = pthread_create(&thread_file[p], NULL, thread_read_file, &struct_data_file[p]);

        }

    init = 0;

    }

    // main loop
    while (1) {

        change_or_not(&offset, &check_id, &change_it);
        usleep(50000);
        fprintf(stdout,".%u.",change_it);
        fflush(stdout);
        pretend_texture_blending(&change_it);

        for ( p = 0 ; p < 4 ; p++ ) { // updating data if ready, destroying mutex when done, etc...

            // lock mutex
            mutex_err[p] = pthread_mutex_lock(&struct_data_file[p].read_mutex);

            if ( mutex_err[p] != 0 ) {  
                fprintf(stderr, "pthread_mutex_lock(3) error: %s\n",strerror(mutex_err[p]));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            // end lock mutex

            // data update routine
            // is data ready: check variable 'reading' from the struct_data_file struct
            // 2            -> yes : update + destroy mutex 
            // 1 or 0 -> no : unlock mutex

            if ( struct_data_file[p].reading == 2 ) { // data is ready
                if (file_content[p]) free(file_content[p]);
                file_content[p] = (char *)malloc(strlen(struct_data_file[p].content)*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(file_content[p],struct_data_file[p].content);
                struct_data_file[p].reading = 0;
                mutex_err[p] = pthread_mutex_unlock(&struct_data_file[p].read_mutex);
                if (mutex_err[p] != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Error destroying mutex: %s\n", strerror(mutex_err[p]));
                }
            } else {
                mutex_err[p] = pthread_mutex_unlock(&struct_data_file[p].read_mutex);
                if ( mutex_err[p] != 0 ) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "pthread_mutex_unlock(3) error: %s\n",strerror(mutex_err[p]));
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
            // end checking if data is ready
        }

        if ( change_it == 1 ) {
            for ( p = 0 ; p < 4 ; p++ ) {
                if ( struct_data_file[p].reading == 0 ) {
                    if ( data_update_done[p] == 0 ) {
                        thread_res[p] = pthread_create(&thread_file[p], NULL, thread_read_file, &struct_data_file[p]);
                        data_update_done[p] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ( change_it == 2 ) {
            for ( p = 0 ; p < 4 ; p++ ) {
                data_update_done[p] = 0;
            }
        }

    // end main loop
    }
// end main
}
```

the output is

```
thiscontent: abu dhabi:35.6 length was 14 for file /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ad.txt
thread_read_file: mutex unlocked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ad.txt
thread_read_file: mutex locked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/summary.txt
thiscontent: AED/euro:4.09534 length was 16 for file /home/tias/repository/data/change.txt
thiscontent: 11111 length was 5 for file /home/tias/repository/data/summary.txt
thread_read_file: mutex unlocked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/summary.txt
thread_read_file: mutex unlocked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/change.txt
.1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..0..1.thread_read_file: mutex locked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ir.txt
thread_read_file: mutex locked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ad.txt
thread_read_file: mutex locked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/summary.txt
thread_read_file: mutex locked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/change.txt
thiscontent: AED/euro:4.09534 length was 16 for file /home/tias/repository/data/change.txt
thread_read_file: mutex unlocked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/change.txt
thiscontent: abu dhabi:35.6 length was 14 for file /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ad.txt
thread_read_file: mutex unlocked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ad.txt
thiscontent: irsch:14.6.09534 length was 10 for file /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ir.txt
thread_read_file: mutex unlocked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ir.txt
thiscontent: 1111 length was 5 for file /home/tias/repository/data/summary.txt
thread_read_file: mutex unlocked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/summary.txt
.1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..1..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..2..0..1.thread_read_file: mutex locked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ad.txt
thread_read_file: mutex locked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ir.txt
thread_read_file: mutex locked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/summary.txt  
thread_read_file: mutex locked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/change.txt
thiscontent: irsch:14.6.09534 length was 10 for file /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ir.txt
thread_read_file: mutex unlocked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ir.txt
thiscontent: abu dhabi:35.6 length was 14 for file /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ad.txt
thread_read_file: mutex unlocked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/temp_ad.txt
thiscontent: AED/euro:4.09534 length was 16 for file /home/tias/repository/data/change.txt
thread_read_file: mutex unlocked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/change.txt
thiscontent: 1111 length was 5 for file /home/tias/repository/data/summary.txt
thread_read_file: mutex unlocked for file: /home/tias/repository/data/summary.txt
```

the 4 files have constant content.

the first 4 results are always correct (4 threads reading the 4 files, first set of results is always correct for as far as I saw and I have done so many tests).

however when the variable thiscontent is displayed (after the first run), I get additional output or even less output (with the file summary.txt that contains 11111)

for instance:
I got thiscontent: irsch:14.6.09534
I should have got thiscontent: irsch:14.6

Also
I should get all the time:
thiscontent: 11111 length was 5
but sometimes I get 
thiscontent: 1111 length was 5

I do not understand why and cannot fix it.
I am puzzled by the fact that the variable thiscontent is automatic, and thus should get initialized at every function call.
however output reveals different.

it might be a memory allocation issue but I have no idea at the moment.

any help greatly appreciated.

PS: you might find some piece of useless code, this is because the main program is an opengl screensaver that I wrote, and is 1000 lines long.

the code I have posted is an extract from this screensaver, reproducing the issue, but without tons of useless code for this very troubleshooting.

thank you

PS no2: you can copy/paste this code into a file called threads.c and compile it using:

```
gcc -o threads threads.c -lpthread -D_REENTRANT
```

Comment: `files[0] = malloc(1+strlen(file1));` also: `strdup()` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing the file content as a string, but you have not added a nul terminator to it. As such, the string doesn't terminate - the extra output you see is junk that happened to be in memory beyond the content.

Where you have:

```
        fread(thiscontent, 1, length, f);
```

You also need to add the nul terminator:

```
        thiscontent[length] = 0;
```

Comment: yes I did it, it works. I am not sure how I did it before, because it did not work at that time. I added a thiscontent[length]='\0'; and it works allright. thank you

Comment: Yet, there is another race condition to consider: The other processes which write new versions of the file race with the reading inside the worker threads in this code: ``p2:fseek(...); p1:write write write p2:read(length)``. Or  maybe the writing processes lock the files exclusively and that will end up having to be considered.